# Possible to create two instances of NotificationHelper?

Tags: android, download, android-asynctask, android-notifications

So I am trying to implement using `NotificationHelper` to inform users on the progress of the download.

```
public class MapDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    public MapDownload(ArrayList<PlaceDetails> placeList, int travelogueID, Context mContext, String travelogueName){ 
        this.places = placeList;
        this.zoom = 12;
        this.tID = travelogueID;
        mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(mContext, travelogueName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //Create the notification in the statusbar
        mNotificationHelper.createNotification();
    }
}
```

However, I was wondering if it's possible to implement it such that if I launch another `MapDownload` class to download stuff, how can I do it such that both will be running concurrently? It seems that upon launching of the 2nd `MapDownload`, the 1st one disappears, and the previous notification will be replaced by the 2nd one.

Is this a problem of a wrong `AsyncTask` implementation, or wrong way of using `NotificationHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `NotificationHelper` is, is it from a third party library?

However, when creating a notification you have to provide an ID. If the same ID is reused later, the previous notification get replaced. See [NotificationManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) documentation.

Maybe that what is happening.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure, I followed the guide from here: http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/#comment-285 ... Would NotificationManager be an easier solution to this?

Comment: You can use `NotificationCompat.Builder`, provided by Google compatibility library. It is quite easy to use: [Creating a simple notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification)